# How do I fill an imported DXF?

Tags: mesh, import, faces, extrude

I import an image I created in AutoCAD.  I tried as lines and as an object.  Turned it into a mesh and used fill.  I cannot get the results I am trying to achieve.  Any advise?
[image: dxfimagehelp]

Comment: You'll probably need to do that in sections. Upload your Blend file and we'll have a look. https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: You have to keep in mind in Blender a single face can't contain holes. All the edges of a face must be continually connected one way or another by vertices.

Answer (score 2):

My advice is to learn how to use the various available tools for filling.  There's an F2 add-on that has a bunch of useful tools and here I'm going to use two indispensable tools that you should explore further, *Bridge Edge Loops* and the edit-mode *Knife Tool*

Here is a crude approximation of your file.  Note that I don't have as many vertices, but the concepts here will work for you:

[image: crude approximation of the original model]

This isn't the only way to do this, but it works well for me on geometry like yours. You will have to adapt it based on the actual vertex layout of your object.

From here there are many possible approaches.  I'm going to start by bridging edge loops.  Here's the first easy to bridge loop:

[image: First edge loop selected]

But there's a problem.  The edge parallel to the Y axis means that the bridge tool will complain.  So I delete it.  We'll put it back shortly.

Then I use the Bridge Edge loops tool from the Edge Menu:

[image: Edge menu showing bridge edge loops]

This gives

[image: partial fill]

The important thing to remember here is that the two sides to be joined must each have the same number of vertices.  Since your geometry will be different than my sample, you'll have to deal with that as you go.

Do the same thing for the loops on the other side:

[image: More edge loops bridged]

Put back the edge we deleted by selecting the endpoint vertices and typing <kbd>F</kbd>.  Then select all of the vertices that make up the edges of the unfilled area:

[image: Selecting the remaining vertices]

and type <kbd>F</kbd> again to make that into a giant face.

[image: completely filled]

We could stop here, but we've just created an ugly N-gon and that could cause problems later so next I use the knife tool to add some edges.  The first one goes along the Y axis, so type <kbd>K</kbd> to start the tool.  Click on the top vertex and then drop down to click on the bottom vertex.  When you have them both selected, type <kbd>Enter</kbd> to finish the cut:

[image: added the first knife tool edge.]

A few more cuts and we're down to one N gon, over at the right side of the X axis.

[image: almost done]

Now it's a matter of judgement.  You can leave the N-Gon, as in that position it might not cause issues.  You can dissolve the vertex, flattening the outer circle slightly or you can create more geometry to get rid of the N-gon.  The right answer will depend on what you want the object for.  Here's additional geometry:

[image: Final all quad version]